# SEO for country in domain name and URL?

Tags: seo, url

For a country wide directory, if the country is already in the domain name as below, is it better for SEO if it is also in the url?

```
country.com/country/province/region/community-activity.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Aim for clarity.

I'm assuming you don't have different countries on the domain, though the advice on URLs is general anyway.

Keep URLs short and descriptive - that means not repeating the country. The easier the URL is to read, the better.

Also remember that long URLs are truncated on search result pages, or may be replaced by breadcrumbs e.g. https://example.com > Category > Subcategory

Google's examples to avoid are extreme, but illustrate my point:

Avoid:

- Using excessive keywords like
  "baseball-cards-baseball-cards-baseballcards.htm".
- Having deep nesting of subdirectories like
  ".../dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/dir6/page.html".

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/7451184